# Mistake in finding KCL and KVL in op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, math, active-filter, kirchhoffs-laws

I have the following op-amp circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flSDaG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know that \$\text{V}_1=0\$ and \$\text{V}_3=0\$ in the case of an ideal op-amp circuit. I wrote the following KCL equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_0=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
0=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6+\text{I}_8
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

And the following KVL equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, I tried to LTspice to simulate this circuit for me and I used Mathematica to find the mathematical result. But they did not gave the same result. Is there a mistake in my equations?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why so many currents, and voltage nodes? You only need the two nodes at the inverting inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second KVL equation is wrong. That should be I1 = (V1-V2)/R2, since I1 goes through R1 and then all of it goes through R2 as well. Otherwise you're saying that I2 completely cancels out I1, making I4=0, which you can't assume.